# How to customize text and number alignment different in Excel?

Tags: excel

I have a table with a column that has a mix of text and number values. I want to customize the format of these values such that the characters/text are left-aligned and numbers are right-aligned.

How would I do this? Since it is a dataset with over 10,000 values, I can't do it manually.

I would appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: If you remove all alignments, text should align to the left by default and numbers aligned to the right. Unless you have numbers stored as text.

Comment: I would take a look into VBA to do this, or at least try what Jerry said. But if you did want to do it in a macro style, then I think vba would be your best choice.

Comment: @Jerry: how do you remove all alignments? I can't seem to do that.

Comment: Select the column, and click on the alignment button that is active. If you have numbers stored as text, put `1` somewhere in the workbook > copy > select the column in the table > paste special > multiply.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by put 1 somewhere in the workbook?

Comment: I selected the column, which I then copied. Then clicked paste special then multiply, but the text was missing but the numbers were right

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
Sub qwerty()
    Set r1 = Selection.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers)
    Set r2 = Selection.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues)
    r2.HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
    r1.HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
End Sub
```